# Comportamento indesejado loop mysql_fetch_assoc

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Estou tendo problemas em um loop while onde tem uma função `mysql_fetch_assoc` que resgata um valor de uma coluna em uma tabela chamada pedidos na coluna entregue.

Fiz um `if` pra ver se tiver um 's' de sim na coluna entregue, que fizesse algumas alterações com JavaScript que altera algumas cores e coloquei um botão escrito 'pedido ja entregue' que quando clicado coloca um valor 's' na coluna entregue na tabela pedidos.

O grande problema no código é que se você clicar no botão 'pedido ja entregue' da última linha recuperada, mesmo se as outras linhas não tiverem o 's' recebem a marcação JavaScript que eu fiz como se fosse pedido já entregue.

```
<?php

include 'conn.php';

$query_select = "SELECT cliente.id_cliente, cliente.nome, cliente.telefone, cliente.endereco, cliente.bairro, cliente.email, pedidos.id_pedido, pedidos.produto, pedidos.qtde, pedidos.preco,
                    pedidos.registro, pedidos.observ, pedidos.datahr, pedidos.entregue FROM cliente, pedidos WHERE cliente.id_cliente = pedidos.id_cliente";

$result = mysql_query($query_select, $connect);

if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0){

    echo '<div class="sem-pedidos">Sem pedidos para Acompanhamento.</div>';
    exit;
}


while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {


?>

        <div class="pedido">
            <div class="nome-cliente" style="width:250px; float:left"><strong><?php echo mb_strtoupper($row['nome']); ?></strong></div>
            <div class="registered" style="width:300px;float:left"><i>Registrado por <?php echo $row['registro'];?> em <?php echo $row['datahr'];?></i></div>
            <div class="telefone" style="width:200px;"><strong><?php echo $row['telefone']; ?></strong></div>
            <div class="email" style="width:200px;"><?php echo $row['email']; ?></div>
            <div class="produto"><?php echo $row['produto']; ?></div>
            <div class="endereco"><?php echo $row['endereco']; ?></div>
            <div class="bairro"><?php echo $row['bairro']; ?></div>
            <div class="qtde" style="float:left"><strong>Qtde. </strong><?php echo $row['qtde']; ?></div>
            <div class="preco"><?php echo $row['preco']; ?></div>
            <div class="observ"><strong><i>OBS. <?php echo $row['observ']; ?></i></strong></div>
            <div class="status" id="status"><strong>Status:</strong><span class="carrega-status"> Entrega em aberto</span></div>
            <div class="field">

                    <a href="entregue.php?id_pedido=<?php echo $row['id_pedido']; ?>" title="clique se pedido ja foi entregue ao cliente">
                        <img src="bt.jpg" />
                    </a>    


            </div><!-- fim div class field -->

                <?php
                    if($row['entregue'] == "s"){

                        echo '<script>

                                $(".field").remove();
                                $(".carrega-status").addClass("entregue");
                                $(".carrega-status").html(" Pedido ja Entregue");
                                $(".pedido").addClass("entregue-ok");   


                                </script>';

                    }


                ?>


        </div><!-- fim div class pedido -->

<?php 

// finaliza o loop
}
```

Comment: [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que acontece é o seguinte: você está setando o javascript para uma classe (.pedido, .field). Todas as linhas tem essa mesma classe. Pra resolver você teria que definir o javascript por id (#pedido01, #field01, etc).

Dessa forma o javascript vai afetar apenas aquela linha, e não todas.

> Editado: Versão sem javascript:

```
<?php

include 'conn.php';

$query_select = "SELECT cliente.id_cliente, cliente.nome, cliente.telefone, cliente.endereco, cliente.bairro, cliente.email, pedidos.id_pedido, pedidos.produto, pedidos.qtde, pedidos.preco,
pedidos.registro, pedidos.observ, pedidos.datahr, pedidos.entregue FROM cliente, pedidos WHERE cliente.id_cliente = pedidos.id_cliente";

$result = mysql_query($query_select, $connect);

if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0){

    echo '<div class="sem-pedidos">Sem pedidos para Acompanhamento.</div>';
    exit;
}


while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {


    ?>

    <div class="pedido <?php if($row['entregue'] == 's') { echo 'entregue-ok'; } // adiciona a classe entregue ?>">
        <div class="nome-cliente" style="width:250px; float:left"><strong><?php echo mb_strtoupper($row['nome']); ?></strong></div>
        <div class="registered" style="width:300px;float:left"><i>Registrado por <?php echo $row['registro'];?> em <?php echo $row['datahr'];?></i></div>
        <div class="telefone" style="width:200px;"><strong><?php echo $row['telefone']; ?></strong></div>
        <div class="email" style="width:200px;"><?php echo $row['email']; ?></div>
        <div class="produto"><?php echo $row['produto']; ?></div>
        <div class="endereco"><?php echo $row['endereco']; ?></div>
        <div class="bairro"><?php echo $row['bairro']; ?></div>
        <div class="qtde" style="float:left"><strong>Qtde. </strong><?php echo $row['qtde']; ?></div>
        <div class="preco"><?php echo $row['preco']; ?></div>
        <div class="observ"><strong><i>OBS. <?php echo $row['observ']; ?></i></strong></div>

        <?php if($row['entregue'] == "s") { // se estiver entregue, exibe um, senão, exibe outro ?>
        <div class="status" id="status"><strong>Status:</strong><span class="carrega-status entregue"> Pedido ja Entregue</span></div>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <div class="status" id="status"><strong>Status:</strong><span class="carrega-status"> Entrega em aberto</span></div>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php if($row['entregue'] != "s") { // só vai exibir se não estiver entregue ?>
        <div class="field">
            <a href="entregue.php?id_pedido=<?php echo $row['id_pedido']; ?>" title="clique se pedido ja foi entregue ao cliente">
                <img src="bt.jpg" />
            </a>    
        </div><!-- fim div class field -->
        <?php } ?> 

    </div><!-- fim div class pedido -->

    <?php 

                // finaliza o loop
}
```